# Restrict Comments Page For Wordpress Members

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, member

In the **comments** section of the WordPress admin panel, there are options such as **confirm**, **edit**, **delete**, **remove** and **ip address** appears. I want nobody to see except the administrator. I want to do this for all status.

To which file will I write the code?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please include more details in your question so that others can answer effectively. In particular describe what you have tried specifically, and why that wasn't enough to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything for it. It doesn't shows to other users it just shows to users with admin rights (on a new installation) if you do edit user roles and define editors and managers etc then you can define what they can do and what they can't.

Have you tried registering as a user on your own blog and checking it out? Start there.

Comment: Actually I tried a few plugins but it was not enough. I normally prevented the editing of comments. then I wanted to test it. I realized that. Anyone who knows Wordpress can access all comments when they write something like **edit-comments.php?p=1234&comment_status=approved** in the link. Now I removed all the buttons, but I do not know how to make an administrator query. I will continue to fix it from the code section until I get a response. Thanks for the answer.